# Caliburn.Micro-Multiple shell support

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, caliburn.micro

I have to develop a WPF application with two windows, main window in primary monitor are other other one in secondary monitor. Uses shall be able to work on each windows independently, but while closing the main window child window also need to be closed. If I understand correctly , it requires two shells and conductors. Is there any way to create multiple shells using Caliburn.Micro to achieve this scenario?

Thanks in advance

I couldn't find a way to manage multiple shells/windows using Caliburn.Micro framework

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.